# Unable to identfy why file is being requested

Tags: html, wordpress, http, http-status-code-404

Hello I am working on a site and using the developer tools in chrome I see Request file `undefined?1428992352055` being requested that my server returns a 404 for.  I am unable to determine why or where this file is being requested.  **It also does not occur every time you load the page**, usually on reloads.   Below are the headers, I think this is all that is needed but I have searched and searched and am unable to figure out what is going on with this file.  Any advice is appreciated.

There is no caching taking place and I have searched the entire server for this string in hopes of removing the reference to it.  I have searched the internet for this issue and am unable to find out what is causing it.

```
Remote Address:216.172.182.170:80
Request URL:http://example.com/undefined?1428992352055
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:4910
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 14 Apr 2015 06:19:14 GMT
Expires:Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=91
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips DAV/2 mod_bwlimited/1.4
Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Pingback:http://example.com/xmlrpc.php
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.39
Request Headers
view source
Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__utma=41034800.1981457984.1428284260.1428541875.1428547896.5; __utmc=41034800; __utmz=41034800.1428547896.5.3.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=http%3A%2F%2Fwww..com%2Ftestimonials; word; _ga=GA1.2.1981457984.1428284260; PHPSESSID=4c6d6e257019f77756205ce29170d54e; wp-settings-1=libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26editor%3Dtinymce%26wplink%3D1%26urlbutton%3Dnone%26imgsize%3Dfull%26advImgDetails%3Dshow%26hidetb%3D1%26posts_list_mode%3Dlist%26post_dfw%3Doff%26mfold%3Do%26align%3Dleft; wp-settings-time-1=1428991051
Host:.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
1428992352055:
```

While reading over my post to make sure there weren't too many mistakes this line stood out at me.  `X-Pingback:http://example.com/xmlrpc.php` so I went to the server and here is the content from that file that may be the culprit.

```
<?php
/**
 * XML-RPC protocol support for WordPress
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Whether this is an XML-RPC Request
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('XMLRPC_REQUEST', true);

// Some browser-embedded clients send cookies. We don't want them.
$_COOKIE = array();

// A bug in PHP < 5.2.2 makes $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA not set by default,
// but we can do it ourself.
if ( !isset( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ) ) {
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
}

// fix for mozBlog and other cases where '<?xml' isn't on the very first line
if ( isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) )
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = trim($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

/** Include the bootstrap for setting up WordPress environment */
include('./wp-load.php');

if ( isset( $_GET['rsd'] ) ) { // http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/blogs/gems/tech/rsd.html
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=' . get_option('blog_charset'), true);
?>
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.get_option('blog_charset').'"?'.'>'; ?>
<rsd version="1.0" xmlns="http://archipelago.phrasewise.com/rsd">
  <service>
    <engineName>WordPress</engineName>
    <engineLink>http://wordpress.org/</engineLink>
    <homePageLink><?php bloginfo_rss('url') ?></homePageLink>
    <apis>
      <api name="WordPress" blogID="1" preferred="true" apiLink="<?php echo site_url('xmlrpc.php', 'rpc') ?>" />
      <api name="Movable Type" blogID="1" preferred="false" apiLink="<?php echo site_url('xmlrpc.php', 'rpc') ?>" />
      <api name="MetaWeblog" blogID="1" preferred="false" apiLink="<?php echo site_url('xmlrpc.php', 'rpc') ?>" />
      <api name="Blogger" blogID="1" preferred="false" apiLink="<?php echo site_url('xmlrpc.php', 'rpc') ?>" />
      <?php
      /**
       * Add additional APIs to the Really Simple Discovery (RSD) endpoint.
       *
       * @link http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/blogs/gems/tech/rsd.html
       *
       * @since 3.5.0
       */
      do_action( 'xmlrpc_rsd_apis' );
      ?>
    </apis>
  </service>
</rsd>
<?php
exit;
}

include_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-IXR.php');
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php');

/**
 * Posts submitted via the XML-RPC interface get that title
 * @name post_default_title
 * @var string
 */
$post_default_title = "";

/**
 * Filter the class used for handling XML-RPC requests.
 *
 * @since 3.1.0
 *
 * @param string $class The name of the XML-RPC server class.
 */
$wp_xmlrpc_server_class = apply_filters( 'wp_xmlrpc_server_class', 'wp_xmlrpc_server' );
$wp_xmlrpc_server = new $wp_xmlrpc_server_class;

// Fire off the request
$wp_xmlrpc_server->serve_request();

exit;

/**
 * logIO() - Writes logging info to a file.
 *
 * @deprecated 3.4.0
 * @deprecated Use error_log()
 *
 * @param string $io Whether input or output
 * @param string $msg Information describing logging reason.
 */
function logIO( $io, $msg ) {
    _deprecated_function( __FUNCTION__, '3.4', 'error_log()' );
    if ( ! empty( $GLOBALS['xmlrpc_logging'] ) )
        error_log( $io . ' - ' . $msg );
}
```

Comment: Well i dont see any errors in my console.

Comment: I know, it is sporadic.  It seems to be the second time you request a page. But not always.  Which is even more strange to me.  i will add that symptom to my post as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reloading it several times and didn't get any error. If you think **xml-rpc** is the culprit then just remove it from the header. If you are not using any remote posting features its always good to remove it as many times it results in security issues. To remove it just include this in your functions file

```
function remove_x_pingback($headers) {
    unset($headers['X-Pingback']);
    return $headers;
}
add_filter('wp_headers', 'remove_x_pingback');
```

Comment: I went ahead and added that code to my functions file as you were wise to point out it is a security issue and as I don't need it, it's a good idea. However it was not the cause of my issue unfortunately, I was mistaken in thinking it was.   +1

Comment: Why do you have transition script directly added to the html? Add it in a separate file, and i think the issue is in your js. In some files i see that you have added your own functionality. Try separating them from the original files and create a new file with all your amendments. I also see bad use of comments in the html. And when you write your own jquery replace $('#element') with jquery('#element'). I think its conflicting with the other files and so you are getting errors.

Comment: Ok I will make those changes and report back.  I made all of the changes to the jquery statements but no luck.  I will make the rest of the changes...